# Ctrl+l works in powershell but NOT in conda powershell

Tags: powershell, anaconda, conda

The exception that I got is the following

```
Exception:
System.IO.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.Console.SetWindowPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ProcessOneKey(ConsoleKeyInfo key, Dictionary`2 dispatchTable, Boolean ignoreIfNoAction, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.InputLoop()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReadLine(Runspace runspace, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected behavior is that `ctrl+l` is equivalent the command `clear`, i.e. the screen is cleared and the prompt is located in the top of the terminal window.
Running on Windows 10, Miniconda 64 bit.

Comment: Try updating the key handler to execute `Clear-Host` instead of PSReadLine's bultin `ClearScreen` function: `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+l' -ScriptBlock { Clear-Host }`

Comment: It works in many cases but not for one specific. I am working with a dell laptop connected to a dock station where it  is connected an external monitor. The normal powershell works in any condition. The conda powershell work in any condition but when it is on the laptop builtin screen AND full screen, then `ctrl+l` triggers the error I described. In every other conditions it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, try re-binding the `Ctrl+l` key handler to a custom scriptblock that simply executes `Clear-Host` (of which `clear` is an alias):

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+l' -ScriptBlock { Clear-Host }
```